# How would I root my HTC without computer

Tags: rooting, htc-one

I want to root my HTC but I'm not sure how I would do this and I have no computer access........ Please help.

Tori

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. You should edit your question and provide necessary information for people to actually help you. What phone (i see you have [tag:htc-one] but you should say that in your question, along with your exact model. Also, explain what methods you have tried already.

Comment: I have a HTC one m7 I think by at&t. I haunt tried anything yet I need something that is free and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Root Master apk from this site - http://www.nextwap.net/mobile/vE4C-rxxce/root_master__english_version_.html

Just install and click the button. I tested it with my Samsung, but it should also work with HTC, depending on system you have.

Comment: I dont know what kind of system I have.

Comment: Is it.supposed to not be in English conserns  a little BIT

Comment: Well, sorry for that, because most of the apps that root phone, are in Chinese or Japanese. This is a minor translation that should suffice ;)

Comment: I don't have a computer and can unlock bootloader what do I do.